# My React/Redux API wont log out properly shows [[PromiseValue]]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Quite new to coding but hitting hurdles with a React/Redux API.

I'm following Bucky Roberts' YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiLVAXlVYR0) & ive replaced his static names object with an API that i then pull into my reducer.

This logs out the data fine, as an array - but when i try to pull it *in* to my Container, i get either a `map is not a function` error (even though it is an array) or if i log out `console.log('props: ', this.props)` i get [[PromiseValue]] with the array[10] showing.

But i'm pretty sure drilling into that in my component would be a no go.

CONTAINER:

```
class UserList extends Component {

  createListItems() {
    console.log('props: ', this.props);
    return this.props.users.map((user) => {
      return (
        <li
          key={user.id}
          onClick={() => this.props.selectUser(user)}
          >
          {user.name}
          </li>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        {this.createListItems()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    users: state.users
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({selectUser: selectUser}, dispatch);
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserList);
```

API:

```
const MyData = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(function(data1) {
    return data1.json()
  }).then(function(data2) {
    return data2
  }).then(function(data3) {
    console.log('API RESPONSE: ', data3)
    return data3
  })

export default MyData;
```

MyData is then pulled into a reducer, then into `combineReducers({})` and the data *should* show back in `mapStateToProps` as above in the container. What Am I Doing Wrong? I feel like it's something to do with resolving Promises but my api actually logs everything out correctly. So is it something to do with having API data passed in higher up, in `createStore` or?:

```
import MyData from './MyData'

export default function() {
  return MyData
}
```

Comment: Your data is a promise, not an array?

Comment: Please post up your reducer.

Comment: @Bergi thanks dude. Not so hot on my JS Promises so i've been doing some reading/practice yesterday & this morning.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to deal with API requests is to put them inside actions and use some middleware to handle asynchronous functions. I'm not sure what is going on with your API function, but anyway consider this solution:

In componentWillMount call an action which fetches users, example with redux-thunk middleware:

```
export function fetchUsers() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_USERS,
      payload: data
    });
  }
}
```

Then you won't have a promise in reducer, but json object and you will be able to map the users, but remember that there is a split second when you don't have users to map, so you have to handle this condition to avoid error:

```
  createListItems() {
    if(this.props.users.length > 0) {
      return this.props.users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <li
            key={user.id}
            onClick={() => this.props.selectUser(user)}
          >
          {user.name}
          </li>
        )
      })
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for that. I will take a look at Thunks today/tomorrow and come back to mark you correct. Was there a reason you used axios and not fetch? Also through research yesterday i've noticed i was using Promises a bit wrong.

Comment: There is no specific reason of using axios in this case, I just used to handle requests by axios, but be careful with extracting data from the response. I'm not sure whether you can pull out the { data } object instead of assigning response to the new const.